# Gmail API users.labels.list doesnot return fields

Tags: gmail-api

Gmail API users.labels.list does not return fields

messagesTotal
messagesUnread
threadsTotal
threadsUnread

Is this a bug in the GMAIL-API ?

Comment: List Labels only lists the lables in the GMail account without giving the details. In order to get the details , you have to use Get Labels. Not sure if this is a bug or design intent.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that it returns the complete users.labels resource which includes
 id
labelListVisibility
messageListVisibility
messagesTotal
messagesUnread
name
threadsTotal
threadsUnread
type

Answer (score 1):

You wont get the complete users.label resource in return to list() call as is the case with other list calls in the Gmail API, to make the API lightweight and robust. So what you need to do is:

1. Call users.labels.list() to get the list of all the label IDs for a given user
2. Call users.labels.get(labelID) to get complete users.label resource having message counts

This is by design and hence not the bug in API.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation should be clear about this

Comment: If it is by design the the API Explorer should not show the fields in the fields selector and there should be clear documentation.